# how can I get the value from a selected looped checkbox?

Tags: php, html, mysql, loops

What I'm trying to do is make the user choose checkboxes to add locations for a manager which only shows locations in the database with no manager. I can't find a way to get the value of which checkbox(es) the user chooses. Does anyone ha a way?

```
<?php
$i = 0;
$getLocationForManager = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM locations WHERE manager = '';");
while ($location = mysqli_fetch_array($getLocationForManager)) {
?>
    <input type="checkbox" id="location-input" name="location-input" value="<?php echo "$location[locationId]" ?>">
    <label for="location-input"><?php echo "$location[locationName]" . ", " . "$location[area]" . ", " . "$location[Country]" ?></label><br>
<?php
    $i++;
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming I'm understanding this correctly, you want to see which values have been selected when the user submits the form that the checkboxes are attached to?

If that's the case then you want to rename the input name value to `name=location-input[]` and when submitted, you will have an array of values in `$_POST['location-input']`

See: https://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.post.php for more information.